# Add node or a scene created with Javafx to fxml

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I try to add a TreeTableView which i have created by coding to right side of  my splitpane. The SplitPane has fix Id: splitId and right side of it has the Id splitidRight. I have created splitpane and added it to anchorepane by scenebuiler. Then I have crated BorderPane with menubar. Then i add splitpane to the center of BorderPane. Now I want to add the treetable to the rightside of splitpane. The Error is `javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane cannot be cast to javafx.scene.control.SplitPane` but beside this error i am not sure if i am doing the insertion at the right place.

```
public class Main extends Application {
private DataConstructor dc = new DataConstructor();
private BorderPane rootLayout;
private Stage primaryStage;


TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>("Functions");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(Main.class, args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    primaryStage.setTitle("IT-Saturation");

    initRootLayout();
    showOverViw();
    makeTreeTable();
}

private void makeTreeTable() {
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Pane(), 1200, 1800);
    Pane sceneRoot = (Pane) scene.getRoot();
    root.setExpanded(true);
    //........make treetable.....//

    treeTableView.setPrefWidth(1200);
    treeTableView.setShowRoot(false);
    treeTableView.setTableMenuButtonVisible(true);
     sceneRoot.getChildren().add(treeTableView);

    SplitPane sp = null;
    try {
        sp = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/OverView.fxml"));


    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    StackPane container = new StackPane();
    container.getChildren().add(treeTableView);
    sp.getItems().add(container);
    sp.setDividerPositions(0.3f, 0.6f, 0.9f); // you can tweak it any how

    // primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    // primaryStage.show();

}


/**
 * Initializes the root layout.
 */
public void initRootLayout() {
    try {
        // Load root layout from fxml file.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("/view/RootLayout.fxml"));
        rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

        // Show the scene containing the root layout.
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Shows the overview inside the root layout.
 */
public void showOverViw() {
    try {
        // Load overview.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("/view/OverView.fxml"));
        AnchorPane overView = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

        // Set overview into the center of root layout.
        rootLayout.setCenter(overView);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the main stage.
 * 
 * @return
 */
public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
    return primaryStage;
}
```

This is the rootLayout.fxml (BorderPane)

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="1200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <top>
      <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </top>
</BorderPane>
```

and this is OverView.fxml with splitpane in it:

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="1200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <SplitPane fx:id="splitId" dividerPositions="0.14691151919866444" layoutX="58.0" layoutY="42.0" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="1200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0" SplitPane.resizableWithParent="false">
               <children>
                  <Label layoutX="23.0" layoutY="173.0" text="Function count" />
                  <TextField editable="false" layoutX="1.0" layoutY="225.0" promptText="FuncCount" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="1.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="1.0" />
                  <Label layoutX="20.0" layoutY="315.0" text="Organization count" />
                  <TextField editable="false" layoutX="1.0" layoutY="366.0" promptText="OrgCount" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="1.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="1.0" />
                  <ToggleButton layoutX="30.0" layoutY="487.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Draw/Reset" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
          <AnchorPane fx:id="splitIdRight" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Use a [controller class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers) so you can get access to the UI elements defined in the FXML.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says you're trying to cast the AnchorPane which is the top root node of your OverView.fxml to SplitPane.

Change your line

```
SplitPane = null;
```

to

```
AnchorPane =null;
```

that should solve your error.